# Gradle Play Publisher's minimum Gradle version is at least Gradle 7.0.2 and yours is Gradle 6.5

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-play-publisher

I tried to configure my gradle file to use gradle plugin followig this tutorial: https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher#authenticating-gradle-play-publisher but now i'm getting this error in the title

These is my gradle version:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JurCv.png)

It's warning me to change my gradle version to 7.0.2 and android gradle version to 7

So i change my version to this: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gknqz.png)

The problem is after i did that and sync the project i received this error: `This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 2020.3.1 or newer.`

My android studio is 4.1.3 by the way which i think it's the latest one